# How to add static constructor behaviour with attribute?

Tags: c#

I want to add static constructor behaviour using attribute for class that have same behaviour (in my case static field placeholder substitution).

Actually I am calling static constructur explicitly, with an utility class that perform the static stuf with Reflection :

```
public class Util
{
  public static void perform(System.Type container)
  {
    // do the static stuff (basically initializing readonly fields
  }
}

public class AClass
{
  static AClass()
  {
    Util.perform(typeof(AClass));
  }
  private static readonly string A = "eza";
  private static readonly string B = "$A.dat";
}
```

I would like to use the Utility class in this way :

```
[StaticVerbatimPlaceholderSubstitution]
public class A
{
  private static readonly string A = "eza";
  private static readonly string B = "$A.dat";
}
```

Actually I know how to extend the Attribute class. What bother me is how to make it call at the right time. Actually consuming it during code (in main or controller) doesn't sound like the static constructor (before any instanciation of the class).

If any one can help me and tell where to put the consuming code of the attribute, i'll be really happy.

also if it is possible to have same Utility code (also the consumming part), so that including the reference is enough to provide the behavior, without code adaptation on the client code.

Thanks,

edit with code for comprehension :

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Classe utilitaire pour initialiser les champs de chaines de caractères statiques en lecture seuls.
    /// Cette classe, permet de faire de la substitution de chaine de caractère en utilisant les expressions :
    /// ${...} qui sont remplacer sur place (verbatim) dans la chaine appelante.
    /// Si des autoréférences sont présentes, le code lève une exception TypeInitializationException lors l'appel à la classe.
    /// </summary>
    public class VerbatimPlaceHolder
    {
        public static void ReplaceAll(System.Type container)
        {
            Hashtable computed = new Hashtable();
            Hashtable visited = new Hashtable();

            FieldInfo[] fields = container.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            foreach (FieldInfo field in fields)
            {
                Replace(container, field, visited, computed);
            }
        }

        private static void Replace(System.Type container, FieldInfo field, Hashtable visited, Hashtable computed)
        {
            if (computed.ContainsKey(field.Name)) return;

            if (visited.ContainsKey(field.Name))
            {
                string names = "";
                foreach (string name in visited.Keys) names += (names.Length > 0 ? ", " : "") + name;
                throw new Exception("[ERREUR FATALE] autoréférence dans la définition des champs statiques {" + names + "} de la classe " + container.Name);
            }

            if (field != null && field.IsStatic && field.IsInitOnly && field.FieldType == typeof(string))
            {
                visited.Add(field.Name, field);

                string result = (string) field.GetValue(null);

                Regex placeHolderPattern = new Regex(@"\$\{([_a-zA-Z0-9]*)\}");
                foreach (Match sub in placeHolderPattern.Matches(result))
                {
                    FieldInfo node = container.GetField(sub.Groups[1].Value, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                    if (node == null) 
                    {
                        throw new Exception("[ERREUR FATALE] le champ statique " + sub.Value + " n'est pas défini pour " + container.Name + "." + field.Name);
                    }

                    Replace(container, node, visited, computed);
                    result = result.Replace(sub.Value, (string) node.GetValue(null));
                }

                //removing space and line breaks
                Regex blanks = new Regex(@"[\s\r\n]+");
                result = blanks.Replace(result, " ");

                field.SetValue(null, result);
                computed.Add(field.Name, field);

                visited.Remove(field.Name);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks *nasty*, a bit like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to do?

Comment: The construction loop isn't a problem, the static constructor stops with exception when auto-reference loop are encountered (I may one day develop a version with fixed-point solving on simple grammar). My aim is to provide the placeholdersubstiution as an attribute class.

Comment: You can't make an "external" class initialize your readonly fields.

Comment: And attributes don't do anything unless they are queried. They don't auto-execute code just because an instance of a class is created. Unless you do `typeof(A).CustomAttributes`, your custom attributes simply "sleep".

Comment: does external mean in attribute class? actually it work quite fine with reflection accessor on fields.

Comment: Calling a static constructor explicitly feels *so wrong*...

Comment: I added code of the utility class that actually perform the substitution in static constructor.
@xanatos: I didn't understand the sleeping state for the attribute (is the state of my fields before initialization?)

Comment: Modifying static readonly fields htrough reflexion feels at least as wrong as explicitly calling static constructors. Take a moment to think about your design, you're using clever tricks, but these are certainly not the right tools. And you're setting up a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: As Xantos said, attributes are simply code decorations, they aren't a sign to run any kind of code for the runtime. Until you query them through reflection, they don't do anything, they are simply a decoration. If you want to run code at specific times, you may need to look at a tool like PostSharp, but attributes aren't going to help you with what you are explaining as far as I understand it.

Comment: @Falanxe:actually i know that it isn't a good way, but it is the only way I found to factorize existing code (DAO layer on old application build around years 2003 without Entity Framwork mapping). My problem is that the actual architecture is used on 70 applications, and this is the simplier solution I found to simplify SQL query expression in the DAOs.

Comment: @Ron Beyer : I know that, my problem is where should I put the consumation, so that it will work in both Web (consuming in controller) and Batch (consumming in main) mode and so that the execution sequence keep the logic of static substitution. I need to find something userfriendly.
In java i would have add some Aspect pointcut, to add the behavior on the call of the static constructor. I don't know if there is same thing in c#

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I got to look for *Module Initializer* with IL injection (as per Mono Cecile or Postsharp).

In Web context there exist IAssemblyPosProcessor that permit this kind of behaviour, but this is only web context and I want to make a library working in batch mode also.